# Select groups with more than one distinct value

Tags: r, subset, difference

I have data with a grouping variable ("from") and values ("number"):

```
from number
   1      1
   1      1
   2      1
   2      2
   3      2
   3      2
```

I want to subset the data and select groups which have two or more unique values. In my data, only group 2 has more than one distinct 'number', so this is the desired result:

```
from number
   2      1
   2      2
```

Comment: I have a doubt about your question.  Suppose in the `from` =2, the numbers are `1 2 1`.  Would that fit into the subset criteria?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several possibilities, here's my favorite

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(+var(number)) .SD, by = from]
#    from number
# 1:    2      1
# 2:    2      2
```

Basically, per each group we are checking if there is any variance, if `TRUE`, then return the group values

---

With base R, I would go with

```
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(number, from, FUN = var))), ]
#   from number
# 3    2      1
# 4    2      2
```

---

**Edit**: for a non numerical data you could try the new `uniqueN` function for [the devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table` (or use `length(unique(number)) > 1` instead

```
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(number) > 1) .SD, by = from]
```

Comment: my real data is not nubmer. it's name string. it can be same problem?

Comment: If it isn't numeric, use the `uniqueN` function from the devel version, such as `setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(number) > 1) .SD, by = from]`. If you don't have the devel version, try  `setDT(df)[, if(length(unique(number)) > 1) .SD, by = from]` instead. [Link for the devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
     group_by(from) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(number)>1)
 #    from number
 #1    2      1
 #2    2      2
```

Or using `base R`

```
 indx <- rowSums(!!table(df1))>1
 subset(df1, from %in% names(indx)[indx])
 #   from number
 #3    2      1
 #4    2      2
```

Or

```
  df1[with(df1, !ave(number, from, FUN=anyDuplicated)),]
  #   from number
  #3    2      1
  #4    2      2
```

Comment: Nice alternatives (i was thinking `n_distinct` but left it for you :)), though the last one is probably misleading, so I wouldn't use it

Answer (score 1):

Using concept of variance shared by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg) but doing it dplyr way:

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% 
   group_by(from) %>% 
   filter(var(number) != 0)

    #Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
    #Groups: from

       #from number
   #1    2      1
   #2    2      2
```