# Remove rows of a dataframe if values from a specific column differ within a grouping category

Tags: r, subset, plyr

I have a huge dataframe, but here is a very simplified example:

```
df <- data.frame(Id=c(rep("Mike",8)), Year=c(rep("2015",2),rep("2016",3),
             rep("2017",3)),location=c(rep("A",2),rep("B",3),"D","E","E"))
df
    #  Id   Year location
    #1 Mike 2015        A
    #2 Mike 2015        A
    #3 Mike 2016        B
    #4 Mike 2016        B
    #5 Mike 2016        B
    #6 Mike 2017        D
    #7 Mike 2017        E
    #8 Mike 2017        E
```

My grouping criteria is `Id` and `Year`, so for an specific group (e.g., Mike 2017) there are many rows. I want to remove all rows of a group in which "location" factors are not all equal.

In this case the only group in which not all locations are the same is "Mike 2017". Then, I want to end up with a dataframe like this:

```
#    Id Year location
#1 Mike 2015        A
#2 Mike 2015        A
#3 Mike 2016        B
#4 Mike 2016        B
#5 Mike 2016        B
```

Is there a way to do this by indicating the grouping criteria and the exclusion criteria described above?

Comment: This almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649049/select-groups-with-more-than-one-distinct-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `group_by` `Id` and `Year` and select only those rows which has only one unique value per group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Id, Year) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(location) == 1) %>%
   #To remove grouping from @AntoniosK in the comments
   ungroup()

#    Id  Year  location
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>   
#1 Mike  2015  A       
#2 Mike  2015  A       
#3 Mike  2016  B       
#4 Mike  2016  B       
#5 Mike  2016  B
```

---

The base R version using `ave` would be

```
df[with(df, ave(location, Id, Year, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))) == 1, ]
```

As @AntoniosK mentioned, make sure to convert `location` to character using `as.character` before using `ave` option. If needed you can convert them back to factor.

Comment: The `dplyr` solution will keep the grouping if you don't use `ungroup()` and the base R solution seems not to work with factor variables, but with character variables.