# filter count distinct > 1

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have df as below:

```
ID | Gender
1  | M
1  | F
2  | F
2  | F
2  | F
3  | M
3  | M
3  | F
4  | M
4  | M
4  | M
```

I'd like to **distinct** filter IDs which have more than 1 Gender (filter dirty data as can't have > 1 Gender per person) 
Results should be:

```
ID | Gender
1  | M
1  | F
3  | M
3  | F
```

How can I go about in R using dplyr?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649049/select-groups-with-more-than-one-distinct-value

Comment: @RonakShah not quite.

Comment: @Sotos Well, if you wrap `unique` in all of those solutions it would give you expected output. In any case, it is not an "exact" duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(Gender) > 1) %>% 
  distinct(Gender)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 2
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>   Gender    ID
>   <chr>  <int>
> 1 M          1
> 2 F          1
> 3 M          3
> 4 F          3
> ```