# how to show the duplicates of column 'a' with different values for column 'b'

Tags: r

My problem is as follows, I need to determine the same variants with a different outcome in R.
So I have:

| Variant | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 3 | E |
| 4 | F |
| 4 | F |
| 4 | F |
| 4 | G |
| 4 | G |
| 5 | H |
| 5 | H |
| 5 | H |
| 5 | H |

And my output should be:
Variant
1,
3,
& 4

I know about the functions duplicated, intersect etc but have no clue how to combine them to get what I want.

Comment: Note you need to use `n_distinct()` rather than `n()` as suggested in the dup post. i.e. `df %>% group_by(Variant) %>% filter(n_distinct(Outcome) >= 2)` with the `dplyr` package.

Comment: I believe this would definitely be a dup question, but the dup link seems to be not accurate enough. [Select groups with more than one distinct value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649049/select-groups-with-more-than-one-distinct-value) might be more accurate

Comment: Don't know how, but this works indeed! I also never use the %>%. But it does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
with(df, df[ave(Outcome, Variant, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) >= 2, ])

   Variant Outcome
1        1       A
2        1       A
3        1       A
4        1       B
8        3       D
9        3       E
10       4       F
11       4       F
12       4       F
13       4       G
14       4       G
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like the \. It gives me the following error:  Error: unexpected input in "with(tt_fin, tt_fin[ave(filtered_maf, variant, FUN = \"

Comment: @M.waal You may have an older version of R. You could change the `\(x)` to `function(x)` and it should work

Comment: Indeed, with function(x) it worked. Thank you both for your help!